# Is the order of an except and intersect operation always ignorable?

Tags: c#, linq, list, intersect, except

For me it seems any operation like

```
var list = new List<int>();
// list.Add some elements...
list.Except(anotherList).Intersect(yetAnotherList)
```

is this always the same like:

```
list.Intersect(yetAnotherList).Except(anotherList)
```

I am not 100% sure.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a purely set-theoretic perspective the order does not matter here. In both steps you're just removing elements from `list`. An element is removed from the list if it's either in `anotherList` or *not* in `yetAnotherList`. Whether you switch the operands of the »or« in the previous sentence doesn't make a difference.

To illustrate, let's construct three lists (sets here, because those are set operations):

```
list = { A, B, C, D }
anotherList = { A, B, E, F }
yetAnotherList = { A, C, E, G }
```

Each set here has one element that is in all three sets (`A`), one element that is in each of the other sets, and one element that is only in that set but not in the others. So we have all possible cases for intersection and set difference covered here.

`list.Except(anotherList)` yields `{ C, D }`. Intersecting that with `yetAnotherList` yields `{ C }`.

`list.Intersect(yetAnotherList)` yields `{ A, C }`. Excepting `anotherList` yields `{ C }` again.

Comment: It should probably be also noted that both `Intesect` and `Except` preserve the original order of elements - hence both versions yield the same result.

Comment: Your 2nd sentence is incorrect....kind of a weird way to phrase it. I think you mean you get a list with all elements in yetAnotherList but none of the elements in anotherList.

Comment: @Joey "without all elements in yetAnotherList and without all elements that are not in yetAnotherList" will yield no results.

Comment: @Joey - it might have been hard to understand as you've used `yetAnotherList` twice, instead of both `anotherList` and `yetAnotherList`. Meh.

Comment: decPL: Ah, now it makes sense. I took the comment as a complaint about my wording with the double-negative instead of an actual factual error.

Comment: @decPL: On the order of elements, it's a tricky one. Neither `Except`, nor `Intersect` guarantee preserving order, if I didn't overlook that in the docs. It's a consequence of the easiest algorithm to implement them, but it doesn't seem to be guaranteed. Also any duplicate elements from `list` will be collapsed into single elements, as the result is logically a set. So `[1, 2, 1, 3].Except([2]).Intersect([1, 3])` will yield `[1, 3]`, so I'm not sure it's appropriate to talk about result order here.

Comment: @Joey you are correct - I've based this on the implementation MS provided for both, which clearly preserves the order of elements, but indeed - there doesn't seem to be any 'contractual' guarantee that this will never change. Given that, I believe the correct answer is 'Yes, but...'.

Comment: Ah, `Intersect` guarantees order, but `Except` does not.

Comment: Which is funny, given how they're implemented (hint: quite similar).